# É válido colocar a data na própria pergunta/resposta para poder indicar sobre recursos obsoletos ou não suportados?

Tags: suporte

Eu fico preocupado se as minhas perguntas aqui no site referentes a algum recurso que pode ou não ter se tornado obsoleto ficar confusa para quem lê-la daqui há uns 5 anos.

Então eu costumo colocar de propósito o ano de acordo com o contexto da pergunta.

Está correto fazer isso, ou eu posso deixar por conta do mecanismo de marcação de data do post do próprio site?

Exemplo:

- [Qual é a finalidade do input do tipo "Image"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198094/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-do-input-do-tipo-image)

Veja a imagem mostrando o trecho que coloquei a "especificação da data" (caso alguém edite minha pergunta :p):

[image: Marcação de data no corpo da resposta/pergunta]

Answer (score 3):

Até pode ser, embora desnecessário já que dá para ver quando foi postado. É redundante, mas redundância pode ser bom em alguns casos.

Answer (score 3):

Em **perguntas** a data (ano) me parece ruído essa informação já está em dois (ou três) lugares: Em cima do avatar, o link da última edição e no canto superior esquerdo.

Em uma **resposta** uma indicação de data parece mais relevante pois linguaguens, frameworks etc vão evoluindo com o tempo. Nas Versões mais antigas algumas tarefas são mais trabalhosas e são algumas vezes são simplificadas nas versões mais recentes.

Então imagine que você responda uma pergunta antiga do SOen de 5 ou 7 anos atrás porque descobrir uma nova forma de resolver algum problema, um trecho como

> A partir da versão X lançada em 20xx Y adicinou uma funcionalidade ....

Ou

> Em 20xx o framework abandonou a estrutura antiga ....

Reforça e torna evidente a partir quando é possível utilizar essa nova solução.

Comment: Concordo totalmente. Na maioria dos casos, usar *versões* faz mais sentido do que usar a data. Ainda adiciono que a datação da pergunta pode até ser restritiva. O que impede alguém de responder sua pergunta daqui 5 anos, quando as ferramentas e padrões forem diferentes? É de se presumir que quem responder em 2017 vai fazê-lo com o conhecimento corrent, e quem responder no futuro vai fazê-lo com o conhecimento de então.